# List of mozc shortcuts?

Tags: ime

[Mozc](http://code.google.com/p/mozc/) is a Japanese [IME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) by Google.

I just discovered (by mistyping something) that `zh` converts to `←`, which I find really cool! (In Japanese such arrows are often used). Similarly, `↓↑→` can be obtained using `z` and the vim key for that direction.

I am sure there are other mozc shortcuts that would save me time.
Where can I find a list of them?

*Keywords: 変換　ショートカット*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other readers

The list can be found and modified by accessing mozc settings, and clicking the Romaji table customize button in the general tab.

失礼します。。。

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot! By the way, here is how to access the mosc settings in Ubuntu: `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog`